# ssrs: one static row matrix, multiple columns will not filter out nulls

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, filter, null, matrix

Using a ssrs 2005 matrix client side. I want to list the multiple addresses of one person, hence one row, multiple columns. The Column field is `=Fields!StreetName.Value`. The data details field is `=First(Fields!StreetPrefix.Value) & " " & First(Fields!StreetName.Value)`. The datasource has a row for each address; however, some rows will have nulls since the datasource is composed of outer joins.

The column grouping works, but the first column is always empty, (first 2 rows of datasource are null) addresses appear only after the empty column. I want to filter out nulls on the matrix, but its like the filter is ignored. I have also tried having the dataset return an empty string for a null streetname and setting the filter to `=Fields!StreetName.Value != =""` but no difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Is it not better that you filter your rows in your query? maybe this solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the filer in the right place? You can put it on the matrix and on the group.